# STRING_AGG working on compatibility level < 140

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, compatibility-level, string-agg

I understand `STRING_AGG` is introduced in SQL Server 2017 which is compatibility level 140.

The expected behaviour is to get error message *'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function* when run on 2016 or lower versions.

Got error when I run on on-prem SQL Server (2016). However, it is executing without error when I run on Azure SQL even after lowering compatibility level to 130 and even 110 did not give any error.

Is something changed in compatibility_level behaviour in Azure SQL? Like, both old and new syntax/code/features work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) at the very last line of the remarks section:

> STRING_AGG is available in any compatibility level.

Which means that if you are running an SQL Server version that supports `string_agg` -

- SQL Server 2017 (or higher)
- Azure SQL Database
- Azure Synapse Analytics (SQL DW)

the `string_agg` built in function will work regardless of the compatibility level that set to the specific database you're working with.